# Is "Restore purchases" mandatory for bound-to-account content?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have an app where you can make an in-app purchase under your account. When the purchase is made, the account is set as "premium" (on my external API), so if you log in with the same account on any other device, you'll get the premium content.

Is it necessary to have a "Restore purchases" button in my case ? If it is, what will the button do, if you already can see premium content?

Comment: Yes, a restore button is needed so the user can get back to premium if they switch devices. This option usually shows up at the place where you ask the user to "purchase" stuff - as another option (restore or purchase). If the user already is on premium, you don't need to show the button

Comment: As I wrote, the API knows if the user is premium or not, so he can log in on any other device and he will still get the premium content which is bound to his user name

Comment: But they might be using some other email id and still be able to "restore" their purchase and unlock the premium content? If its non-consumable IAPs, Apple expects you to give the user a Restore option

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using in-app purchase you should probably have the button, you could set as an action a verification at the user's account on your server to see if he has premium or not.